# Equivalence between two definitions of left-invariant vector fields

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

**I have the following definition in my notes**
If $M$ is a manifold, we denote by $\mathscr{V}(M)$ the real linear space of smooth vector fields on $M$: A vector field $v \in  \mathscr{V}(G)$ **is called left invariant**, if

$T(l_x)v\equiv(l_x)_*v=v$, for all $x\in G$ ; or, equivalently if

$v(xy)=  T_y(l_x) v(y) ,x,y \in G$...(2)

where $T(\phi)\equiv\phi_*$ is the diferential

**Can someone  exlain why is (2)  equivalent to the initial definition?**

If I try  to prove it I arrive to another expresion. I have that

$T(l_x)v\equiv(l_x)_*v=v$, for all $x\in G$

If I evaluate both sides of the equality (which are vector fields) in a point $y\in G$, I get

$(T(l_x)v)(y)=v(y)$

$T_y(l_x)v(y)=v(y)$

instead of

$T_y(l_x)v(y)=v(xy)$

**Why is this not correct and how do I get (2)?**

Comment: If you push forward  by $l_x$ and end up at $y$, where did you start?

Comment: @TedShifrin at $ x^{-1}y$ ? Actually if I start at y I end up at xy : $l_x(y)=xy$, I had thought about that too,  but I can't figure out why when evaluating two sides of an identity in the same point  as above yields another answer.

Comment: Your line above “instead of” is wrong.